# Why is Magento admin URL so long and complicated on lcoalhost?

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, .htaccess

I have just uploaded Magento on localhost and its URL is simply this `localhost/magento` but when I go on its admin part i.e `localhost/magento/admin` part url redirects to a very complicated & unexpected url i.e `http://localhost/magento/admin/admin/dashboard/index/key/d0635adba364ac457fb10aa4f6147b02c983c632402595b88482d7956d7accf0/`.

Please help me out that how can overcome from this problem? I have earlier uploaded its previous version but then I have not face this type of problem but that I had uploaded directly on server not on localhost.

Comment: Does the admin login screen show? Are you able to login into the admin?

Comment: That is not a concern, Magento is just adding security key as part of URLs to make admin more secure. It is possible that you previously had it off, it is configurable via admin and on by default.

Comment: yes I can login into the screen but the url showing is wierd i.e http://localhost/magento/admin/admin/crypt_key/index/key/fe2632b3d6003f38d3f2403c613a786d7b03bc6c6a241ba8de1b075d37620115/ because i want to show it like localhost/magento/admin

Answer (score 2):

Do not use `localhost` as the domain name. use 127.0.0.1 instead.
Magento is not able to set cookies unless there is a dot in the domain name.

The long number you see in the url is a security key generated based on the action name and a random session key. It is used to prevent CSRF attacks.

Comment: can you please explain little here why ? we are learning from you post

Comment: @Marius, please elaborate more on your answer why you should use this... :P

Comment: @7ochem. Better now?

Comment: Wouw, very nice

Answer (score 0):

It is a security key. Magento check it to know if it is from the current session or not.

If you want to disable it you can go in:
**System > Configuration > Advanced > Admin > Security > Add secret key to URLs >> false.**

But it is not really recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your reply brother , I can only see "system" options as per your path in Backend so please clarify the path.I am using latest Magento so can you please elaborate your URL that from where i can overcome this problem.

Comment: @AshwaniKumar By default the "System" link is in the top menu of your admin far right. See screenshot [here](http://imgur.com/XryRgKe)

Comment: @geoffray have a look at this link http://prntscr.com/9a6mxo & http://prntscr.com/9a6ob7 from where i can see system n its option in different way , the view you are talking about may be of old version.

Comment: OK you are using Magento 2 ! The tag `magento-1.9` mislead me sorry. I don't know where this configuration is on M2. But simple question, why do you want to disable this feature ? It very important to prevent against CSRF attacks. Not on a local environment of course but be careful if magento is for a production site.

Comment: @geoffray Thanks but currently I am using it on localhost for learning purpose that's why I want to disable that URL so that I can understand these issues too.